# decoding vtt timestamp data

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a few hundred lines coming from a VTT subtitle file, an example from the suttitle is

```
00:01:03.500 --> 00:01:03.510 align:start position:0%
<c.colorCCCCCC>fourth guess it came from a broken</c><c.colorE5E5E5> home
 </c>

00:01:03.510 --> 00:01:08.140 align:start position:0%
<c.colorCCCCCC>fourth guess it came from a broken</c><c.colorE5E5E5> home
a<00:01:04.580><c> father</c><00:01:05.580><c> not</c><00:01:05.820><c> being</c><00:01:05.880><c> there</c><00:01:06.890><c> my</c><00:01:07.890><c> mother</c></c>

00:01:08.140 --> 00:01:08.150 align:start position:0%
a<c.colorE5E5E5> father not being there my mother
 </c>

00:01:08.150 --> 00:01:13.429 align:start position:0%
a<c.colorE5E5E5> father not being there my mother</c>
<c.colorE5E5E5>getting<00:01:09.150><c> married</c><00:01:09.630><c> and</c><00:01:11.360><c> the</c><00:01:12.360><c> abuse</c></c><c.colorCCCCCC><00:01:12.659><c> started</c><00:01:13.049><c> at</c></c>

00:01:13.429 --> 00:01:13.439 align:start position:0%
<c.colorE5E5E5>getting married and the abuse</c><c.colorCCCCCC> started at
 </c>
```

VTT subtitle files are pretty confusing, but what the goal is to grab all the words within the timestamp tags and the timestamp themselves.
I was thinking preg match but dont know how to accomplish this

```
$pattern = "<([^;]*)>";
preg_match_all($pattern, $lineContent, $allintag);
```

Is what I got but stopped there.

```
array(
00:01:03.510,
00:01:04.580,
00:01:05.58,
00:01:05.820,
00:01:05.880,
00:01:06.890,
00:01:07.890,
00:01:08.140,
00:01:09.150,
00:01:09.630,
00:01:11.360,
00:01:12.360,
00:01:12.659,
00:01:13.049
)
array(
'fourth guess it came from a broken home',
'father',
'not',
'being',
'there',
'my',
'mother',
'getting',
'married',
'and',
'the',
'abuse',
'started',
'at'
)
```

Comment: Try `preg_match_all('~<(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)>|<c>\s*(?<text>.*?)</c>~', $lineContent, $allintag)`

Comment: Half way, this returns an array with the timecodes only, not the words inbetween one timecode tag to the next

Comment: See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/PK4Xo) and the [regex demo](https://3v4l.org/PK4Xo).

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: Or, maybe https://3v4l.org/00WmD is better

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
'~<(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)><c>\s*(?<text>.*?)</c>~'
```

If the time and text groups are not consecutive use

```
'~<(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)>|<c>\s*(?<text>.*?)</c>~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CNi1K9/1).

**Details**

- `<` - a `<` char
- `(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)` - Group "time": 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, `.` and then 1+ digits
- `>` - a `>` char
- `<c>` - literal `<c>` text
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<text>.*?)` - Group "text": any  0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `</c>` - literal `</c>` text.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/BGB5p):

```
$lineContent = "<00:01:13.650><c> time</c><00:01:13.920><c> and</c> 
 <00:01:14.780><c> that's</c><00:01:15.780><c> what</c>";
if (preg_match_all('~<(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)><c>\s*(?<text>.*?)</c>~', $lineContent, $allintag)) {
    print_r($allintag["time"]);
    print_r($allintag["text"]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 00:01:13.650 [1] => 00:01:13.920 [2] => 00:01:14.780 [3] => 00:01:15.780 )
Array ( [0] => time [1] => and  [2] => that's  [3] => what )
```

Comment: OK, its still dropping a few words. See the edited code

Comment: @PeterFriedlander Try `'~<(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)>|<c(?:\.color(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}){3})?>\s*(?<text>.*?)</c>~s'`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/CNi1K9/2)

Comment: Thank you! But I inserted the formula into the regex code and even the demo link, but it's not formatting correctly.

Comment: @PeterFriedlander You have recursive structure in your data. Hence, it is not clear what you need to get. Please explain what output you are looking to get.